# Проблема в верстке

Tags: html, css

Помогите, я запутался. Откуда вылазит это маленькое белое пространство?

CSS:

```
#wraps {
    width: 1840px;
    height: 100%;
}

#wraps .home_wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    width: 900px;
    height: 800px;
}

#wraps .game_wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    width: 900px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wraps">
    <div class="home_wrap">
        <button onclick="$('#wraps').animate({marginLeft: '-900px'}, 500);">TEST GO</button>
    </div>

    <div class="game_wrap">
        <button onclick="$('#wraps').animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);">back GO</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте после закрытия div.home_wrap сразу же открыть следующий div без пробелов и переноса строки.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan получилось, спасибо! Оставьте комментарий, как ответ, чтобы я его пометил, как верный.

Answer (score 3):

`display: inline-block;` - строчные снаружи, блочные внутри.
Т.е. отступ - это проблем между "строками"

Решение 1 - располагать `inline-block` друг за другом без переноса на др строки и без пробелов между ними:

```
<div class="home__wrap>...</div><div class="game__wrap">...</div>
```

Решение 2 - задать `.game__wrap{margin-left: -5px; }`

[Дополнительные варианты решения проблемы.](http://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html)

Comment: больше никаких вариантов нету? получается не красиво, если убрать отступ, а margin-left не подходит

Comment: @ikerya, http://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html

Answer (score 1):

это пробел между блоками, которые вы сделали inline элементами